# How to use ReactiveFormsModule and validations for dynamically added controls in Angular?

Tags: html, forms, angular, validation, typescript

I have a couple of fields connected to the FormBuilder like this.

```
constructor(private builder: FormBuilder) {
  this.form = builder.group({
    "firstName": [...],
    "lastName": [...]
  });
}
```

In the markup, besides the fix controls, I'll also have an unknown number of input boxes. It's starting with zero and can be increased, as the user clicks on a button, which adds a new input box by each click. There'll be also a removal button for each input box so the number of those is fully dynamic.

```xml
<div class="input-caption">FirstName</div>
<input type="text" formControlName="firstName">

<div class="input-caption">LastName</div>
<input type="text" formControlName="lastName">

<div id="options"></div>
<button (click)="addOption()">Add option</button>
```

As the dynamically added fields need to be validated, I feel that I need to declare them in the group definition. I have no idea how, though.

When I googled, I got a bunch of hits on `[(ngModel)]` but I also read that it's supposed to be used with the `FormsModule` and not `ReactiveFormsModule` as discussed in [a blog](http://blog.angular-university.io/introduction-to-angular-2-forms-template-driven-vs-model-driven/#disqus_thread).

How should I approach it? Is double-bound *ngModel* the only option?

**Edit** based on the answer.

HTML

```xml
<div *ngFor="let tag of []; let i = index;" [formGroupName]="i">
  <div class="input-caption">Tag</div>
  <input formControlName="name"> -->
</div>
```

TS

```js
constructor(private builder: FormBuilder) {
  this.form = builder.group({
    "firstName": [...],
    "lastName": [...],
    "tags": this.builder.array([]),
  });
}

addTag(): void {
  (this.form.controls.tags as FormArray).???;
}
```

I've also tried to specify a hard-coded array in the markup as follows but didn't get to see any controls being rendered.

```xml
<div *ngFor="let tag of [{'name':'uno'},{'name':'duo'}]; let i = index;" 
     [formGroupName]="i">
  <div class="input-caption">Tag</div>
  <input formControlName="name"> -->
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your scenario is the purpose of a FormArray. See the docs here: https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms#use-formarray-to-present-an-array-of-formgroups

The docs show an array of FormGroups, but you can also use it to create an array of FormControls.

Here is an example from my application:

```
    this.productForm = this.fb.group({
        productName: ['', [Validators.required,
                           Validators.minLength(3),
                           Validators.maxLength(50)]],
        productCode: ['', Validators.required],
        starRating: ['', NumberValidators.range(1, 5)],
        tags: this.fb.array([]),
        description: ''
    });
```

My "tags" look like this:

[image]

I set default values into these controls like this:

```
    // Update the data on the form
    this.productForm.patchValue({
        productName: this.product.productName,
        productCode: this.product.productCode,
        starRating: this.product.starRating,
        description: this.product.description
    });
    this.productForm.setControl('tags', this.fb.array(this.product.tags || []));
```

You can find my sample code here: https://github.com/DeborahK/Angular2-ReactiveForms In the "APM" or "APM - Updated" folders.

This is the code from the Pluralsight course: `Angular Reactive Forms` here: https://app.pluralsight.com/library/courses/angular-2-reactive-forms/table-of-contents

Comment: Thanks. That's helping but I'm still a bit stuck, because I'm trying to approach it a bit differently. I don't have an explicit model, using only `private form: FormGroup`. So I'd need to access the "tags" and add a new group to that array when clicking the add-button. However, trying `(this.form.controls.tags as FormArray).???` doesn't produce anything that I recognize as useful. How would you do in this scenario? I've updated the question with the new syntax.

Comment: I added a separate reply since it was a different answer. Hope that helps. If not, maybe you can create a plunker that demonstrates more what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want this code to work, you just need to change it to an array:

```
<div *ngFor="let tag of ['uno','duo']; let i = index;" 
     [formGroupName]="i">
  <div class="input-caption">{{ tag }}</div>
  <input formControlName="name"> -->
</div>
```

And they don't really need to be form groups. It would probably be simpler if they aren't:

```
<div *ngFor="let tag of ['uno','duo']">
  <div class="input-caption">{{ tag }}</div>
  <input [formControlName]="tag"> -->
</div>
```

And if this is all you need ... then you don't really even need FormArrays.